# Multilevel study -- am I accounting for an effect twice?

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis

I am running a multilevel study, with the level setup of ObservationsOverTime/Headmaster/Schools/SchoolType

I want to predict headmaster job satisfaction levels, and one of my predictors is the level of funding the school receives. I believe that headmasters's job satisfaction depends not on the absolute level of funding, but on the difference of funding to the average school of the same type. Because he/she is likely to compare with similar others.

So my predictor is "funding_of_the_school - average_funding_of_same_school_type"

One thing I am wondering about now: Am I accounting twice for school type effects here? Does my inclusion of SchoolType effectively capture the average funding already?